# Cannot find the option "Add to Index" in Eclipse Git

Tags: git, eclipse

I have a eclipse java project I created a Git repository and did Team>share project. I created a new branch and now I would to add the project and new changes to this branch. I cannot find the "Add to Index" option to add all changes to staging area before commit it.

What is the problem? Here image for the options that I had

[click here for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hukb5.jpg)

Comment: _Add to Index_ is only shown when there is something to add. By the way, your Eclipse and EGit seem to be outdated.

Comment: When I push the branch to remote repository, all new classes does not show there. How could I update the branch on remote repository?

Comment: Adding to the earlier comment, "Add to Index" is only applicable in the "Git Staging" view, to operate on files in the "Unstaged Changes" panel.

Comment: Yes I need to move files from unstaged changes to staged changes

Comment: I have some classes in my local repository, which I would like to push it to the remote repository. I did push branch, but nothing on the remote repository changed.

Comment: How to reproduce the issue in the current Eclipse? Currently, it is not clear to me what you did with which result.

Comment: I have a project on Github. I download it and I added some classes to this project. I created a new branch on local repository and all my new classes is there. I am trying to push this branch to remote Github repository, but it did not changed on the remote one.